# sort items by a particular property in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a series of objects being displayed in a table. Two of the properties of the objects are "isGroup", a boolean which returns true if the account is part of a group, and "groupName" which returns a string.

What I am trying to achieve is a table which lists first all of the accounts that are not part of a group, followed by a group by group list of all of the accounts in particular groups, with the group name showing once at the top of each block.

I am a knockout beginner, what I have so far looks like this:

```
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: dashboard.widgets.modelPortfolio.models">
        <!-- ko if: isGroup === false -->
        <tr data-bind="if: isGroup === false">
            <td class="labelCol"><span data-bind="text: accountName"></span></td>
            <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: modelName"></span></td>
            <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: driftPercentage"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko-->
        <!-- ko if: isGroup === true -->
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol"><b><span data-bind="text: groupName"></span></b></td>
            <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: modelName"></span></td>
            <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: driftPercentage"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol"><b><span data-bind="text: accountName"></span></b></td>
            <td class="col"></td>
            <td class="col"></td>
        </tr>
       <!-- /ko -->
   </tbody>
```

It displays the heading for the groupname above each account that is part of a group, so my issues are:

1) getting it to only show once per group, and
2) getting all of the accounts that belong in each group to show up under that group.

There is no set number of possible groups.
From my research so far I have seen a util called arrayGetDistinctValues which I think might be useful.

Comment: Can you post your View Model code as well to help understand that a little more?  I feel it should be possible to do using one or two [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a stab at something that should work without being able to see your specifics.  Firstly, in the viewmodel, I've created two [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).  The first loops through the objects (which I've assumed are in an observable array called `obj`).  It returns a new array containing the objects that are not in a group.  The second one builds up another array of key/value pairs, where the key is the groupName and the value is another array containing the objects in that group.

I've assumed (again without seeing your viewmodel specifics) that the modelName and driftPercentage is common across all objects in a group, and will just use the values from the first object to populate the values for the group.

```
var vm = {
    ungrouped: ko.computed(function () {
        var ret = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < obj().length; x++) {
            if (!obj()[x].isGroup)
                ret.push(obj()[x]);
        }
        return ret;
    }),

    grouped: ko.computed(function () {
        var ret = [];
        function getGroup(groupName, modelName, driftPercentage) {
            for (var x = 0; x < ret.length; ret++) {
                if (ret[x].groupName == groupName)
                    return ret[x];
            }
            var g = {
                groupName: groupName,
                modelName: modelName,
                driftPercentage: driftPercentage,
                objects: []
            }
            ret.push(g);
            return g;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < obj().length; x++) {
            if (obj()[x].isGroup) {
                var g = getGroup(obj()[x].groupName, obj()[x].modelName, obj()[x].driftPercentage);
                g.objects.push(obj()[x]);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    })
}
```

The HTML then renders these computeds one at a time, looping first over `ungrouped`, then over `grouped`.  Whilst looping over `grouped`, it then also loops over the sub-array of objects within that group:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dashboard.widgets.modelPortfolio.models">
    <!-- ko foreach: ungrouped -->
    <tr>
        <td class="labelCol"><span data-bind="text: accountName"></span></td>
        <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: modelName"></span></td>
        <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: driftPercentage"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko-->
    <!-- ko foreach: grouped -->
    <tr>
        <td class="labelCol"><b><span data-bind="text: groupName"></span></b></td>
        <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: modelName"></span></td>
        <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: driftPercentage"></span></td>
    </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: objects -->
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol"><b><span data-bind="text: accountName"></span></b></td>
            <td class="col"></td>
            <td class="col"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Hopefully this will help - if not I'm happy to clarify further if we can know more about your viewmodel etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can approach this from your view model. Looking at your template, I am going to infer that the "header" row for a specific group is defined by something on your view model.

As such, the way I would approach this is to look at each row as an entity in a collection (observable array or a computed function that returns an array). That way, the presentation is decoupled from the ordering of your groups. On top of this, your root object for the table's rows (defined by your `foreach` on the `<table>` tag) should be a complex object:

```
this.groups = ko.computed(function () {
    return [
        {
            name: "group1",
            entities: [ /* .... your model objects */ ]
        },
        {
            name: "noGroup",
            entities: [ /* .... your model objects */ ]
        }
});
```

Then, you can have your template iterate through the groups and determine the presentation based on the `name` attribute:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: groups">
    <!-- ko if: name === "group1 -->
        <tr>
          <td class="labelCol"><b><span data-bind="text: groupName"></span></b></td>
          <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: modelName"></span></td>
          <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: driftPercentage"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- ko foreach: entities -->
            <tr data-bind="if: isGroup === false">
              <td class="labelCol"><span data-bind="text: accountName"></span></td>
              <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: modelName"></span></td>
              <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: driftPercentage"></span></td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko-->

    <!-- ko if: name === "noGroup" -->
        <tr data-bind="if: isGroup === false">
          <td class="labelCol"><span data-bind="text: accountName"></span></td>
          <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: modelName"></span></td>
          <td class="col"><span data-bind="text: driftPercentage"></span></td>
        </tr>
   <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

So this results in having your view model's attribute add some metadata to it to help with laying out your HTML in the template. A benefit of this is that it helps decouple the presentation from how the data gets structured by the ViewModel. Templates should basically just react to the data that is sent to them - how the ViewModels organizes/sorts that data is up to the ViewModel. In your case, I believe that this structure of the template and ViewModel's data will also accommodate different sort orders of the groupings - so if "group1" should come first, the template won't care - it will only render the "group1" html when it sees an object with that value.

Does this help?